# Comparing strings with NULL gives wrong results

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I have a scenario where in I need to compare data of two columns. Both columns are Strings.
below are the scenarios to be covered

Scenario 1 : if column 1 has a value and Column 2 is NULL = its a Mismatch

Scenario 2 : if column 1 is NULL and Column 2 has a Value = its a Mismatch

Scenario 3 : if column 1 has a value and its found in Column 2 (any position in set of strings) =Not a Mismatch

Scenario 4 : if column 1 value matches with Column 2 value= its not a Mismatch

Scenario 5 : If both columns are NULL = its not a mismatch

[image: Expected output image]

Note : I have tried to achieve the above scenarios by creating a report level variable and have defined as below

```
if (IsNull([column1)) then "Y" 
else 
If(Match([column1];"*[column2]*");"Y";"N")
```

The above logic holds good for scenario 2, 3, 5 but do not cover the rest.

I use SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.1 Support Pack 6 Patch 4
Version: 14.1.6.1848

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=If IsNull([COLUMN1]) And IsNull([COLUMN2]) Then "No" 
Else If  Not (IsNull([COLUMN1])) And  Match([COLUMN2];"*" + [COLUMN1] + "*") Then "No" 
Else "Yes"
```